# pdf generation code works fine on localhost but not working at server

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

**file size of generated pdf is 13mb working fine on localhost but not working on server..**

generated file contain more than 650 pages..

I cant figure out that what is the problem someone please help as I am new to Itextsharp

And is it possible to reduce file size while generation file..

C# CodeBehind file

---

```
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
    doc.SetMargins(-55f, -80f, 15f, 20f);
    MemoryStream ots = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Response.OutputStream);
    doc.Open();

    SqlConnection conmain1 = new SqlConnection(conne);
    conmain1.Open();
    SqlCommand cmdmain1 = new SqlCommand(queryforvoucher, conmain1);
    SqlDataReader drmain1;
    drmain1 = cmdmain1.ExecuteReader();

    while (drmain1.Read())
    {
        string classname = (drmain1["ClassName"].ToString());
        string section = (drmain1["SectionName"].ToString());
        string session = (drmain1["SessName"].ToString());
        string grnum = (drmain1["StDeGrNumber"].ToString());
        string fname = (drmain1["StDeFatherName"].ToString());
        string sname = (drmain1["StDeName"].ToString());
        string dis = (drmain1["StDeDiscount"].ToString());
        string mfees = (drmain1["StDeFees"].ToString());
        string id = (drmain1["VoIssueDate"].ToString());
        string dd = (drmain1["VoDueDate"].ToString());
        string pd = (drmain1["VoPeriod"].ToString());
        string vd = (drmain1["VoValidDate"].ToString());
        string sli = (drmain1["VoSlipId"].ToString());

        doc = BindindData(doc, classname, id, section, session, grnum, pd, fname, sname, dis, mfees, dd, vd, Convert.ToInt32(sli));
    }
    conmain1.Close();
    pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
    doc.Close();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Voucher_"+p+".pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Write(doc);
    Response.End();
```

**Web Config**

```
  <location path="vouchergeneration.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" maxRequestLength="29296" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="209715200" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

Comment: What does "not working on server" exactly means? What happens when working on server?

Comment: Could be wrong configuration of the database. Could be an out-of-memory problem: Why is the file 13 MByte? Are you sure you're creating the PDF correctly? Could be a problem accessing resources (e.g. images that can be found). Could be all sorts of things, but you aren't giving us sufficient information to help you.

Comment: I dont know why pdf file is not generating...on server
the file size is 13 because it fatches data of students form database..
I dont know that I am creating the PDF correctly or not But it is working and downloading on localhost. 
although i attach my file... Thanks in advance..


[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B28zv518vg4pSnJyZVhEVmZtMkU/view?usp=sharing) .cs File...
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B28zv518vg4pNy10TlFyQjNiczQ/view?usp=sharing) .aspx file
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B28zv518vg4pWDF5UzdjTkxZS0U/view?usp=sharing) web.config file